# How to dereference a string that might be null in LINQ

Tags: c#, string, linq, dereference

Let's say I need to compare an object to other objects stored in a table called Indexes in my DB.
I need to compare by the object's `X` property, which is a string, but it might be `null`.

I also have to trim my comparedObject's X property before comparing.
I tried to do the following:

```
List<Guid> Ids = DataContext.Indexes.Where(ci =>
                 (comparedObject.X != null && ci.X != null ? 
                 ci.X == comparedObject.X.Trim() :
                 (ci.X == null || ci.X == string.Empty) && (comparedObject.X == null || comparedObject.X == string.Empty))).Select(ci => ci.Id).ToList();
```

And even though `comparedObjects.X` is `null` it still throws a null reference exception for the `comparedObject.X.Trim()` expression.

I assume that happens due to the linq conversion?

Is there a prettier way to trim the `X` property without having to assign `comparedObject.X` an empty string in case it's null before the query ?

EDIT:
I'd like to elaborate - this query was reduced for simplicity here, I am also comparing about 6 other properties. I'd like to keep this in 1 query and not separate to 2 queries that differ in the `X` property alone. 
Trimming outside the query is my current solution, I was hoping for a in-statement solution in case there is any :)

Thanks!

Comment: What do you want to select in your if and you else if?

Comment: try to use string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace() - by looking at the query it seems that the trim() statement should not be executed.

Answer (score 3):

> And even though comparedObjects.X is null it still throws a null
>   reference exception for the comparedObject.X.Trim() expression.

you better do a null check before the linq statement

```
if(comparedObject !=null && !string.IsNullorEmpty(comparedObject.X))
{
    // your code goes here 
}
```

below code

```
(ci.X == null || ci.X == string.Empty) && (comparedObject.X == null || comparedObject.X == string.Empty)
```

can change to

```
string.IsNullorEmpty(ci.X) && string.IsNullorEmpty(comparedObject.X)
```

And i would change code as below

```
List<Guid> Ids = DataContext.Indexes.Where(ci =>
                 (string.IsNullorEmpty(ci.X) && string.IsNullorEmpty(comparedObject.X)) || ci.X == comparedObject.X.Trim())
                .Select(ci => ci.Id).ToList();
```

Comment: I would still have to compare the X property (trimmed) within the LINQ statement later on. So I'll need to Trim it before the statement, and I'm trying to find a more elegant solution than that :)
I'm also comparing other properties (about 6) which I removed for the sake of simplicity. I'd like to prevent the query duplication since I'll have to do the same query without the X property in the statement on the else clause.

Answer (score 0):

may be you can try:

```
List<Guid> Ids = DataContext.Indexes.Where(ci =>ci.X != null ? ci.X == comparedObject.X==null?"":comparedObject.X.Trim() :
                                 (comparedObject.X == null || comparedObject.X == null)))
                            .Select(ci => ci.Id).ToList();
```

Comment: That's basically what I'm doing, but since it's inside a LINQ query the .Trim() is still executed and null reference is achieved :)